# undefined index for cookie even though it's set

Tags: php, html, cookies

i have a remember me part for my login page where you enter your email and then press continue, if a cookie is set with your email your password will be in the password part and if not it would be empty.
my cookies are set successfully and you can see them in the cookies part however when i call them there's an undefined index error.

```
if(!empty($_POST['remember'])){
    setcookie ("admins_login".$email,$Pass,time()+ (365 * 24 * 60 * 60),'/');
}
```

this is in my parent class in my login function and the cookie will be set if login is successful.

```
public function rememberMe($email){
    if(isset($_COOKIE["admins_login$email"])){
        return $_COOKIE["admins_login$email"];
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

this is my rememberme function that is in another class that extends the former one.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["login2"])){
    echo $admin->rememberMe($_POST['email']);
}
?>
```

this is what i put in my placeholder for the password input.
however no matter what email/username i enter the password is always empty ive checked to see if it goes inside my if and the cookie is never set even though i can see it in the browser's cookie part.
my main problem is with php not reading my cookie. i can just store something in it and check if the cookie is set.
please do not report if you don't understand me, english is not my first language.

Comment: You are storing the user's password in a cookie?

Comment: @user3783243 yes for the remember me part

Comment: That is a very very very very bad idea, from a security standpoint.

Comment: Scrap that idea and look into creating tokens instead.

Comment: But as to your problem, check that the value of `$_POST['email']` in `echo $admin->rememberMe($_POST['email']);` is the same as is in the email part of `$_COOKIE["admins_login$email"]`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i've checked, its the same

Comment: _Small Hint_ 'Remember me' does not need anything private/secret to work, (you dont actually need a password to log a user in) all you need is the knowledge that the remember me will last for a period of time. Can I suggest you create a token and store it with the user on the database and send that token with the cookies. When they come back, you check that the token exists in the user table, then do whatever it is you do to indicate that a user is logged in

Comment: @RiggsFolly if i want to use cookies and then just say if my cookie is set, login; it wont do it either cause the cookie is still considered unset even though i've set it.

Comment: If you look at the Error logs, do you see errors like `Headers already sent`

Comment: `setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including and tags as well as any whitespace.`